# AS2- My movieclips are stored in an Array, yet I cannot access their properties or methods

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, movieclip, hittest

I have stored a series of duplicated movieclips in an array, so that I can check to see if any of the bullets are hitting any of the enemy MCs.  However, Flash will not let me access the properties or methods ON the movieclips.

```
function checkHits(){//checks for hits between enemies and bullets
for (var zz = 0; zz < bulletArray.length; zz += 1)//checks for each bullet
{
for(var yy=0;yy<enemiesArray.length;yy+=1){//checks for each enemy
    trace("enemies loc"+yy+":"+enemiesArray[yy]);
    trace("bullet loc"+zz+":"+bulletArray[zz]);
    if(bulletArray[zz].hitTest(enemiesArray[yy])){
        trace("HIT!");
       removeMovieClip(bulletArray[zz]);
       removeMovieClip(enemiesArray[yy]);
       bulletArray.splice(zz,1);
       enemiesArray.splice(yy,1);
       }//end if
}//end for
 }//end for
```

That is the code, which runs ever frame and checks to see if anythign is hitting.  The hitTest never registers, but if I change the hitTest objects, the removeMovieClip does work.  So I can reference the object successfully, but I cannot access any properties.  If I try, they always come up undefined.

For reference, here is the code for the bullet generation.  Note that both these functions are root-level functions.

```
function dupeCircle()
{
//trace("Dupe circle initiated");
duplicateMovieClip(circlebase, "circle" + circleCount, circleCount);
bulletArray.push("circle" + circleCount);
trace(bulletArray[0]._width);
circleCount += 1;
}
```

Comment: I think you would need to rephrase your question to get help on it. As I understand it, you don't share the code for the problem, "access their properties or methods", and also - "if I change the hitTest objects, the removeMovieClip does work" - if it works, than what exactly is your question?

Comment: For example, the trace(bulletArray[0]._width) returns "undefined", whereas removeMovieClip(bulletArray[0]) will remove the object from the stage.  And when I say change the hitTest objects, I mean that if I change it to simply say "circle0" and "wiggler0", which are the object's instance names, rather than pulling them from an array

Comment: Won't bulletArray.push("circle" + circleCount) add a string, like "circle1", to the array, rather than adding a reference the MovieClip? If I remember AS2 correctly, duplicateMovieClip() returns a reference to the MovieClip created, so you could try storing that in a local variable and then add that to the array.

Comment: Well, I've tried using
 bulletArray.push(duplicateMovieClip(circlebase, "circle" + circleCount, circleCount));, but that still returns undefined.  I have tried it with the "_root" and without

Comment: Also, if I trace the duplicate method it returns "undefined" for some reason

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you would want to use `attachMovie()` instead of `duplicateMovieClip` if you are creating an instance of the clip in the library rather than copying an already-created object. In which case, rewrite the creation code like this:

```
_root.attachMovie(circlebase, "circle" + circleCount, circleCount);
bulletArray.push(_root["circle"+circleCount]);
```

Comment: I actually solved it myself by using the class-based duplicate method rather than the global one.  But thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.  It is because I was using the global version of duplicateMovieClio rather than the class version.  Thanks again!